# What are some nice characterizations of $\mathfrak{c}$-compact spaces?

Tags: general-topology

We can generalize the notion of Lindelöf spaces to consider spaces whose open covers admit a $\kappa$-sized subcover, for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$.

I imagine that $\kappa$ compact spaces in general have been studied in the past, and a single math.SE answer would likely not do justice to this whole topic. Thus, let's restrict ourselves only to $\mathfrak{c}$-compact spaces. That is to say, spaces whose open covers admit a continuum-sized subcover.

> Is there a nice characterization of $\mathfrak{c}$-compact spaces?

Comment: The definition is the characterisation.

Comment: BTW it’s usual to define $X$ to be $\kappa$-compact when every open cover of $X$ has a subcover of size $<\kappa$. So you ask about $\mathfrak{c}^+$-compact spaces. $\omega$-compact is usual compact and Lindelöf is $\aleph_1$-compact. The compactness number $l(X)$ is defined as the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $X$ is $\kappa$-compact.